# Deciding prototype of functions

Tags: c, data-structures, functional-programming, function-pointers

I have 2 data structures as following:

```
struct data_type{
    char name[20]; 
    int (*check_equal)(void* a, void* b);
}
```

and

```
struct attr_data{
    int data_type; 
    void* (*get_func)(void* record); //Not sure about prototype of this function
}
```

The first data structure is actually a structure used for different logical datatypes like string and int(c datatypes of short and int would come under "int" logical type). So, I have an array of this data_type struct with 2 elements in it: one with name as string and other one with name as integer. "check_equal" function for string is just a call to function strcmp() using args a and b given, which are typecasted to char*. Similar is case with the check_equal function for "integer" element. But notice here that in this implementation, the "check_equal" function would require pointers to 2 integers passed.
    The second data structure actually is a meta data for any other data structure like:

```
struct abc{
    char* a;
    int b;
 }
```

For every member variable in struct abc, supposed I maintain an instance of struct attr_data in some array. Ideally a get function for some member variable should always return value of that member variable and not a pointer to that. Thus get function for member a in struct abc should return char* but that for b, should return an int. Now I need to use these get_funcs to directly pass an argument to the check_equal function of struct data_type. But since prototype of check_equal function is (void*,void*), using this get_func fails. 
Can anyone help me out deciding prototypes of function pointers used here? Can someone help understand the issues behind typecasting int to void*?

Comment: You should use a `struct` with a `enum` which hold the data type and a `union` for the actual data. Then pass this structure as argument and depending on the enum, perform the appropriate operation. That's actually how high level languages implement dynamic typing

Comment: That seems interesting. Can you elaborate more with some example?

Answer (score 0):

`enum e{CHAR, INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE, CHARP, INTP, ......}`

you can use these data types as a reference and using switch case you can do desired operation with with different data type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example where `struct data` can either hold a string or an integer.

```
struct data {
    enum {
        INT,
        STRING
    } type;
    union {
        int integer;
        char* string;
    } value;
};
```

Now you can try to do some comparison:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char str1[] = "test";
char str2[] = "test";
char str3[] = "another test";

int check_equal(struct data *v1, struct data *v2)
{
    if(v1->type == INT && v2->type == INT) {
        return v1->value.integer == v2->value.integer;
    }
    else if(v1->type == STRING && v2->type == STRING) {
        return strcmp(v1->value.string, v2->value.string) == 0;
    }
    else return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
   struct data var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6;

   var1.type = INT;
   var2.type = INT;
   var3.type = INT;
   var1.value.integer = 3;
   var2.value.integer = 3;
   var3.value.integer = 4;

   var4.type = STRING;
   var5.type = STRING;
   var6.type = STRING;

   var4.value.string = str1;
   var5.value.string = str2;
   var6.value.string = str3;

   printf("var1 = var2 : %d \n",check_equal(&var1,&var2)); // 1
   printf("var1 = var3 : %d \n",check_equal(&var1,&var3)); // 0

   printf("var4 = var5 : %d \n",check_equal(&var4,&var5)); // 1
   printf("var4 = var6 : %d \n",check_equal(&var4,&var6)); // 0

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I actually wanted to let go off the if else checks. I figured out a way to use union. I am passing this union type var as both arguments to the check_equal function and also as the return type for the get_func. I don't know if this is the right way to solve the problem, but it works!